# "Your most recent save data could not be loaded at this time" error message

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

[image]

This is what happens when I open GTA Online. A message displays saying:

> Alert
>
> Your most recent save data could not be loaded at this time. Please return to Grand Theft Auto V and try again later.

What I think happened is that it was saving and as it was saving, my internet crashed, so I got disconnected from Online. Now that screen shows up when trying to enter online. Please help because I don't think I can use online anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this and it means what it says – it can't be loaded at this time. Give it some time and you'll be able to get back in.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your modem and or router, go into single player first. Start online from there. If it still occurs, press the Xbox button while it's loading(works with some online games I find). If this all does not work, go to single player, choose online, play solo session. And if your still having issues, make sure your internet hasn't been slowed, and that anything that doesn't need to be on (the pc, your phone connected via wifi, or any tablets), be disconnected or off.
Finally, book a support ticket with rockstar on their site.